# How to copy mp3 files from computer to Android phone

Tags: file-transfer

First post, not sure whether this question fits here. Just bought Xiaomi m4 phone. When connecting it to computer I see a new drive with 10MB capacity and 0MB free. Can't copy anything there.

How can I transfer my mp3 files to my phone if not this way ?

Comment: 10MB? That's not a lot! I guess it's 10GB?

Answer (score 1):

You should install drivers for your device first. When you connect device to computer select from settings on device, usb connection most related to mass storage. Just google for android usb connection mass storage. After this you can see in your computer internal phone storage and also external sd card(if you have one) as drives.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Airdroid (available on Play Store) and use the website ( http://web.airdroid.com/ ) to transfer files from a computer to your Android device.

You don't need any cable to use that application, it uses your wifi connection.

Comment: I prefer to use a local service that stays on the local network. Using Airdroid, Dropbox or Mega means that you share your files with them. Not everybody wants that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different methods to copy files between laptop and phone. I use [**FTPserver**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=nl) (on the phone plus a client like [**Filezilla**](https://filezilla-project.org/) on the laptop) and [**BTsync**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync) over wifi. I don't leave them running, stop them right after using. With BTsync I empty the folders after use and stop the service at my desktop as well.

This doesn't require a cable connection. Another option is Bluetooth, but I'm having mixed experiences with it. More easy options: Dropbox, Mega etc, but I don't like to share stuff over the web.

If you're using Android 4.4 (KitKat) you cannot copy to all folders, due to security settings. Only some filemanagers can do that. Try and see what works. With Btsync use the internal memory, not the external SD card.

Comment: [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) is also very nice. In contrast to FTP, it keeps the file creation information when copying. In contrast to BTsync, you get all the functionality without paying and it's fully open source.